# adding geom_point and geom_line to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6),
                 task=c("p","p","p","p","p","b","p","b","p","p","b","b","b","p","p","b","b","p","p"),
                 value=c(0.3,0.29,0.33,0.33,0.11,0.4,0.15,0.49,0.11,0.4,0.32,0.59,0.6,0.4,0.53,0.63,0.44,0.52,0.55),
                 value2=c(110.7,68.96,122.31,125.91,21.1,160,43.3,136,NA, NA, NA, NA, 195,216,NA, 21.87,27.62,19.43,20.48),
                 data_type=c("value","value","value","value","value","value","value","value","from","to","from","to","value","value","value","from","to","from","to")

)
```

I want to plot the `ID` on the x-axis and then `value` and `value2`  on the y-axis and then use facet wrap with task, so that 2 plots are created on the condition `task`.

What I am struggling with are the different data types. ID=1 for example has min and max values of a range which could be displayed with displayed with `geom_line`, while others have just a single value which can be displayed with `geom_poin`. Also, every ID has `value` and `value2` which have a very different range.

How can I smoothly plot the data with ggplot in a nice way?

Comment: Which lines of ID = 1 are min and max?  You have all four ID = 1 lines coded as data_type = "value"

Comment: for ID = 1 I only have fixed values (indicated as "value");
e.g. for ID = 6 I have min and max values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to reshape your data into long format, and then facet in such a way that you can use a free y-axis.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6),
                 task=c("p","p","p","p","p","b","p","b","p","p","b","b","b","p","p","b","b","p","p"),
                 value=c(0.3,0.29,0.33,0.33,0.11,0.4,0.15,0.49,0.11,0.4,0.32,0.59,0.6,0.4,0.53,0.63,0.44,0.52,0.55),
                 value2=c(110.7,68.96,122.31,125.91,21.1,160,43.3,136,NA, NA, NA, NA, 195,216,NA, 21.87,27.62,19.43,20.48),
                 data_type=c("value","value","value","value","value","value","value","value","from","to","from","to","value","value","value","from","to","from","to")
)

setDT(df)

setnames(df, "value", "value1")

df.long <-  melt(df, measure.vars=c("value1","value2"))

ggplot(df.long, aes(x=ID, y=value)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(variable~task, scales="free_y")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That looks good! Thx! However, do you know how I could differentiate between the different data types and plot those as points that are data_type = value and those as geom_point + geom_line that are of data_type = from/to

Comment: I'd just plot them separately and then combine into a single large figure. You can use something like the `cowplot` package for that.